# phone field with constraint and format

Tags: entities

Is there a way to make a phone field that would only accept numbers (no spaces) and will format them as the user types?

Note: I read somewhere that text fields can be configured that way but I could not find how. I also tried integer field but this feels wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Masked-Input](http://drupal.org/project/maskedinput) module. It does exactly what you are looking for.